# Static library .a file not updating after perform change in .m files

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

I have created static library project using the line script files.

Then I am manually copy .h files and .a file and created a framework. using iOS universal framework method. 
But it's working fine while creating first time. but changed small modification in .m file its **not reflecting in created staic library .a file**.  **but it's working fine while using source files**.

Please let me know if you have face similar type of issues.

Comment: Please describe what you are doing after the source file is changed. Do you build the library manually or do you expect it to be built automatically ?

Comment: building library manually but i am not getting .a file corresponding to updated source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/323026-xcode-does-not-rebuild-app-when-source-file-updated-in-dependent-static-library.html#323031) answers your question, there is a bug in xcode, according to the signature, the post is by a developer who works on the xcode product. The reply to it shows a solution that has worked for me, which is:

- explicitly set the location of the static library to "Relative to Build Products"
- with a good text editor, edit the **project.pbxproj** inside the your project e.g. **MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj** and search for a line like the one below containing your library name. Verify that for the **path=** entry there is no path, and only the filename of your library file. It's nasty to have to do this, but I have found that xcode does not get it right 100% of the time.

  `{isa = PBXFileReference; explicitFileType = archive.ar; includeInIndex = 0; path = libMyLibrary.a; sourceTree = BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR; };`

Answer (score 1):

Do a clean build. The working project might be pointing at the old .a file maybe. Cleanup the project and then add the static library.

Comment: Hi i have created new project then referred that framework.. But no result. After created changed static library project want to build the project?...

Answer (score 0):

check and match the .a file creation date/time to ensure that it has been generated after you have made changes to .m file